# How to apply auto-complete functionality to the cell of ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ag-grid

Auto-complete functionality needs to suggest function names which is in a json format and mentioned below:

```
{
 "id": 260,
 "title": "p_active(Power: number, PowerAngle: number)",
 "type": "PR",
 "category": "AL",
 "structure": "p_active(Power: number, PowerAngle: number)"
}
```

Here, `p_active` is a function name, which needs to be included in the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think ag-grid has support for autocomplete out of the box, with that being said there are 2 possible solutions I can think of:

1. Create a custom Cell Renderer component. This allows you to customize your cell with any component however you want, in this case what you can do is have an input there with auto complete. More info about this:
   https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/
2. Use a ready solution/package - here's a package I found:
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor

Here's a stackblitz with the implementation of autocomplete:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Material Autocomplete with Angular.  I wrap it in a class I created named `AutocompleteCellRendererComponent` which implements AG Grid's `ICellRendererAngularComp`.  It seems to work fairly well ***so far*** (I don't have all the kinks out yet).  I would put the code here if there was anything weird, but it really is just a very straight forward wrapping of a Material Autocomplete in an Angular component with this as the template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="filterInput" panelWidth>
    <mat-autocomplete
        #auto="matAutocomplete"
        [panelWidth]="panelWidth"
    >
        <mat-option class="mat-row" *ngFor="let row of filteredRowData" [value]="getValue(row)">
            {{getText(row)}}
        </mat-option>

    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then the AG Grid column def looks like this for showing an employee autocomplete list in the AG Grid:

```
columnDefs: [
    {
      headerName: 'Employee',
      field: 'employee.name',
      cellRenderer: AutocompleteCellRendererComponent,
      cellRendererParams: {
        autocomplete: {
          source: this.employeeService.getAll(),
          formatter: this.formatEmployeeAutocomplete,
          panelWidth: '320px'
        }
      }
    },
```

As a side note, if you happen to be showing the grid in an `NgbModal`, I had to add this to my stylesheet:

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1056;
}
```

...otherwise the autocomplete list shows up behind the modal.